# Why is this cache not getting evicted?

Tags: java, spring, caching

AdminSOAPRunner:

```
@Component
public class AdminSOAPRunner {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminSOAPRunner.class);

    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Autowired
    private AdminAuth adminAuthenticator;

    @Autowired
    private AdminBean adminBean;

    private AccountService accountService;


    private void setBindingProviderByAccountService() {
        WSBindingProvider bindingProvider = (WSBindingProvider) this.accountService;
        bindingProvider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, adminBean.getAccountUrl());
        LOGGER.info("Endpoint {}", adminBean.getAccountUrl());
    }

    private RequestInfo getRequestInfo() {

        RequestInfo requestInfo = new RequestInfo();

        requestInfo.setAppName(adminBean.getAppName());
        requestInfo.setUserId(this.getUserId());
        requestInfo.setTrace(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        return requestInfo;

    }

    public List<ApplyAccountResult> getAccounts(ApplyAccountRequest request) {
        AccountService_Service service = null;

        URL serviceWSDL = AccountService_Service.class.getResource("/Account-service/Account-service.wsdl");
        service = new AccountService_Service(serviceWSDL);

        SOAPHandlerResolver SOAPHandlerResolver = new SOAPHandlerResolver();
        SOAPHandlerResolver.getHandlerList().add(new SOAPHandler(this.adminAuthenticator));
        service.setHandlerResolver(SOAPHandlerResolver);

        if (accountService == null) {
            accountService = service.getAccountService();
        }

        setBindingProviderByAccountService();

        ApplyAccountAccountResponse response = null;
        LOGGER.info("Making a SOAP request.");
        response = AccountService.applyAccount(request, getRequestInfo(), new Holder<ResponseInfo>());
        LOGGER.info("SOAP request completed.");
        return response.getApplyAccountResults();
    }
```

SOAPHandlerResolver:

```
public class SOAPHandlerResolver implements HandlerResolver {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private List<Handler> handlerList;

    public SOAPHandlerResolver() {
        this.handlerList = null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public List<Handler> getHandlerList() {
        if (this.handlerList == null) {
            this.handlerList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return this.handlerList;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
        List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<>();
        if (this.handlerList == null || this.handlerList.isEmpty()) {
            this.handlerList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.handlerList.add(new SOAPHandler(null));
        }
        handlerChain.addAll(this.handlerList);
        return handlerChain;
    }
}
```

SOAPHandler

```
public class SOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private AdminAuth adminAuth;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SOAPHandler.class);

    public MosaicOnboardSOAPHandler(AdminAuth adminAuth) {
        if (adminAuth == null) {
            adminAuth = new AdminAuth();
            LOGGER.info("AdminAuth found null. Creating new adminAuth instance.");
        }
        this.adminAuth = adminAuth;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (outboundProperty) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
            if (headers == null) {
                headers = new HashMap<>();
                context.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
            }
            List<String> cookie = headers.get("Cookie");
            if (cookie == null) {
                cookie = new ArrayList<>();
                headers.put("Cookie", cookie);
            }
            cookie.add(this.adminAuth.getToken());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

AdminAuth:

```
@Component
public class AdminAuth {

    @Autowired
    private AdminBean adminBean;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Admin.class);
    private String token;

    private void generateToken() {

        try {
            AdminTokenHelper adminTokenHelper = new AdminTokenHelper(adminBean.getAutheticationServerURL(), adminBean.getLicense());


            token = adminTokenHelper.getToken(adminBean.getUsername(), adminBean.getPassword().toCharArray());

            LOG.info("Token generation successful");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("Token generation failed");
            LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Token generation failed", ex);
        }
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "tokenCache")
    public String getToken() {
        LOG.warn("Token not available. Generating a new token.");
        generateToken();
        return token;
    }
}
```

ehcache.xml

```
 <cache name="tokenCache" maxEntriesLocalHeap="1" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="895" timeToLiveSeconds="895" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
```

Applcation

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class).profiles(determineEnvironmentProfile());
    }
}
```

In AdminAuth, it uses functional user to generate token. the token generated for authentication expires in 15 minutes. So my purpose was to write cache so that all the calls from ui can use the same token regardless of actual user. So i set the time 14:55 to generate new token. Now the problem comes when it's after 15 minutes and the cache doesn't evict the old toeken so that call uses the old and expired token and it fails. 
I tried different eviction policies like LRU, LFU, FiFO but nothing is working. The calls are coming from ui through tomcat container in spring boot 1.3.

Why is this not getting evicted? What am i missing? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you post your Spring cache configuration?

Comment: @starf I edited the code. Please check above.

Comment: Which version of Ehcache are you using? Have you added a dependency for (Ehcache3) org.ehcache:ehcache etc.?

Comment: version 2.8.3. i have net.sf.ehcache and spring-support-context dependecy. While using @EnableCaching, im using xml. Should there be mapping missing? I'm really confused.

Comment: That's ok to have the ehcache.xml as long as it's in the root of your classpath - i.e. in src/main/resources if using maven. You should add org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache and remove spring-support-context.

Comment: See also the Spring Boot documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html

Comment: Actually i was missing spring-boot-starter-cache dependency. Now its working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `@Cacheable(value = "tokenCache")` with  `@Cacheable("tokenCache")`

Comment: This will make no difference. It's effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

The dependency on `spring-boot-starter-cache` was missing. This prevented Spring Boot from automatically configuring the `CacheManager`. Once this dependency was added, the cache configuration worked.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html